# Visual Studio 2013 publish crash after newest windows 10 update

Tags: c#, visual-studio, asp.net-mvc-4

I used to use VS2013 and set up my profile to publish web project.
It was working as expected in windows 10 until I installed the newest update for windows 10 last night.

Now every time I publish my project then popup says visual studio has stopped working and restarted itself.

I tried clean my project and rebuild, delete profile and import new one. re-install and get the latest Visaul Studio update. None of them worked.

Exception:

> System.StackOverflowException was unhandled
>   Message: An unhandled exception of type 'System.StackOverflowException' occurred in mscorlib.dll

In Event log:

> Faulting application name: devenv.exe, version: 12.0.21005.1, time stamp: 0x524fcb34
>   Faulting module name: MSVCR120_CLR0400.dll, version: 12.0.52512.0, time stamp: 0x5525ef9d
>   Exception code: 0xc00000fd
>   Fault offset: 0x0007e1a8
>   Faulting process id: 0x1128
>   Faulting application start time: 0x01d11f4665107d6c
>   Faulting application path: C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 12.0\Common7\IDE\devenv.exe
>   Faulting module path: C:\Windows\SYSTEM32\MSVCR120_CLR0400.dll
>   Report Id: 6bfdab62-235e-4e00-b23e-4312cf3f276a
>   Faulting package full name: 
>   Faulting package-relative application ID:

Details:

> devenv.exe 
>      12.0.21005.1 
>      524fcb34 
>      MSVCR120_CLR0400.dll 
>      12.0.52512.0 
>      5525ef9d 
>      c00000fd 
>      0007e1a8 
>      1128 
>      01d11f4665107d6c 
>      C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 12.0\Common7\IDE\devenv.exe 
>      C:\Windows\SYSTEM32\MSVCR120_CLR0400.dll 
>      6bfdab62-235e-4e00-b23e-4312cf3f276a

I still have no idea why it crashed, please shed some light if anyone knows anything, thanks!

There are a couple exception before the stack overflow exception which lead to crash. This is the call stack of first exception after I right click project

```
mscorlib.dll!System.Collections.Hashtable.Insert(object key, object nvalue, bool add)   Unknown
mscorlib.dll!System.Collections.Hashtable.Add(object key, object value) Unknown
Microsoft.VisualStudio.dll!Microsoft.VisualStudio.PropertyBrowser.AutomationExtenderManager.GetExtenders(EnvDTE.ObjectExtenders extensionMgr = COM Object, string catID = "{4EF9F003-DE95-4d60-96B0-212979F2A857}", object extendee, System.Collections.Hashtable ht = Count = 1)   Unknown
Microsoft.VisualStudio.dll!Microsoft.VisualStudio.PropertyBrowser.AutomationExtenderManager.GetExtendedObjects(object[] selectedObjects = {object[1]})  Unknown
Microsoft.VisualStudio.dll!Microsoft.VisualStudio.PropertyBrowser.PropertyBrowser.Microsoft.VisualStudio.PropertyBrowser.ILocalPbrsService.GetProcessedObject(object component) Unknown
Microsoft.VisualStudio.dll!Microsoft.VisualStudio.PropertyBrowser.VSPropertiesTab.GetProperties(System.ComponentModel.ITypeDescriptorContext context = {System.Windows.Forms.PropertyGridInternal.SingleSelectRootGridEntry}, object component, System.Attribute[] attributes = {System.Attribute[1]})  Unknown
System.Windows.Forms.dll!System.Windows.Forms.PropertyGridInternal.GridEntry.GetPropEntries(System.Windows.Forms.PropertyGridInternal.GridEntry peParent = {System.Windows.Forms.PropertyGridInternal.SingleSelectRootGridEntry}, object obj = COM Object, System.Type objType = {Name = Inspecting the state of an object in the debuggee of type System.Type is not supported in this context. FullName = Inspecting the state of an object in the debuggee of type System.Type is not supported in this context.})   Unknown
System.Windows.Forms.dll!System.Windows.Forms.PropertyGridInternal.GridEntry.CreateChildren(bool diffOldChildren = false)   Unknown
System.Windows.Forms.dll!System.Windows.Forms.PropertyGridInternal.SingleSelectRootGridEntry.CreateChildren()   Unknown
System.Windows.Forms.dll!System.Windows.Forms.PropertyGridInternal.GridEntry.InternalExpanded.set(bool value)   Unknown
System.Windows.Forms.dll!System.Windows.Forms.PropertyGridInternal.GridEntry.Create(System.Windows.Forms.PropertyGridInternal.PropertyGridView view, object[] rgobjs, System.IServiceProvider baseProvider, System.ComponentModel.Design.IDesignerHost currentHost, System.Windows.Forms.Design.PropertyTab tab, System.Windows.Forms.PropertySort initialSortType) Unknown
System.Windows.Forms.dll!System.Windows.Forms.PropertyGrid.UpdateSelection()    Unknown
System.Windows.Forms.dll!System.Windows.Forms.PropertyGrid.RefreshProperties(bool clearCached)  Unknown
System.Windows.Forms.dll!System.Windows.Forms.PropertyGrid.Refresh(bool clearCached)    Unknown
System.Windows.Forms.dll!System.Windows.Forms.PropertyGrid.SelectedObjects.set(object[] value)  Unknown
Microsoft.VisualStudio.dll!Microsoft.VisualStudio.PropertyBrowser.PropertyBrowser.UpdatePropertyGrid()  Unknown
Microsoft.VisualStudio.dll!Microsoft.VisualStudio.PropertyBrowser.PropertyBrowser.UpdateSelection(bool updateGrid, bool updateComboBox) Unknown
Microsoft.VisualStudio.dll!Microsoft.VisualStudio.PropertyBrowser.PropertyBrowser.OnIdle(object sender, System.EventArgs e) Unknown
System.Windows.Forms.dll!System.Windows.Forms.Application.ThreadContext.System.Windows.Forms.UnsafeNativeMethods.IMsoComponent.FDoIdle(int grfidlef)    Unknown
System.Windows.Forms.dll!System.Windows.Forms.ComponentManagerProxy.System.Windows.Forms.UnsafeNativeMethods.IMsoComponent.FDoIdle(int grfidlef = -2)   Unknown
```

exception:

> "Item has already been added. Key in dictionary: 'WebApplication'  Key being added: 'WebApplication'"}    System.Exception {System.ArgumentException}

Comment: Attach the debugger in a second copy of VS before publishing, then look at the stack trace.

Comment: I tried that, but even I downloaded all possible symbol, the call stack doesn't make much sense and I don't think I can get anything from assembly code either.

Comment: Attach as managed rather than native; native code shouldn't be relevant (and you don't need symbols at all to see managed stacks)

Comment: I attached call stack for the first exception.
By the way, not sure if this is related, but I have conflict warning for this mscorlib.dll when I build my project and I haven't figured out to resolve that conflict yet.

Answer (score 4):

I finally pinned down to the root cause of crash. If I delete obj and bin folder in my project, then publish profile will work. Maybe that's because I have some dll conflict warning when build my project?

I still not sure why this didn't happen in windows 8. Why it behaves differently in windows 8 and 10?

Comment: I have to delete obj and bin before each publish

Comment: I'm having the same problem and this seemed to at least let me publish. You would think Microsoft would test their development tools on Windows 10.  I've had nothing but problems since i switched.

Comment: same problem here, and deleting the obj/bin folders does seem to temp fix it. Tough one as the issue also exists in VS2015! Not sure what to do.

Answer (score 0):

I've had this problem too, and the only way to solve it was to **reinstall Visual Studio**, or you can try first repairing the installation.

Comment: I have this issue as well, after installing Win 10 SP1 or whatever they call it. Instead of reinstalling VS 2013 as you did, I installed VS 2015 but the issue exists there too. Considering I had another issue with Package Manager after the update, I ran the gacutil.exe fix on the dll entity framework. I wonder if there is something related to do for this fix...

Answer (score 0):

I have figured out that the problem is withing the .csproj file.

1. open the file in text editor (i.e. notepad++) and cut off the files section (ItemGroup elements) for after reference
2. save the file
3. open the project in vs2013 
   (I am not sure you need to reopen the vs2013 - but that's what I did).
4. Then close the project in vs2013.
5. paste back all the ItemGroup elements we just cut out
6. resave.
7. publish it again